# Funding the deployer during the deployment of Safe's singleton contract?

Tags: gnosis-safe

My objective is to deploy the Safe app on a custom EVM-compatible network, using [the safe-infrastructure](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure) repository.

I discovered that in order to proceed, I need to request a new deployment at https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory.

After making the request (e.g. [this](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory/issues/110)), the manager from the Safe team generated a transaction (e.g. [this](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory/pull/115/commits/41499ade925ce21379a9b91f63bee1127464ca26)) and instructed me to fund the deployer and execute it. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with how to 'fund the deployer' and execute the transaction.

I have gone through all of the documentation provided, but could not find the instructions for this specific task. Could someone please guide me on how to proceed with funding the deployer and executing the transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of this PR is solely to generate a signed transaction for deploying the contract. In order to actually deploy the contract, you will need to provide funding of `gasPrice` * `gasLimit` to the deployer (i.e. the `signerAddress`) and submit the signed transaction using RPC `eth_sendRawTransaction`.

```bash
curl -X POST "NODE_URL" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction","params":["TRANSACTION"], "jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1}'
```

To verify the correctness of the PR, you only need to confirm that the transaction information is accurate. You can do this by copying and pasting the signed transaction into the website https://flightwallet.github.io/decode-eth-tx/, and checking that the parameters are correct (such as the nonce being set to 0).