# Can I test the whole system UI+smart contracts if deploying singleton smart contract to custom network by myself (instead of waiting the PR)?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I saw here
[Adding a CUSTOM network to Gnosis Safe](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/124174/adding-a-custom-network-to-gnosis-safe)
and here [Funding the deployer during the deployment of Safe's singleton contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/147221/funding-the-deployer-during-the-deployment-of-safes-singleton-contract)
that at first we should wait for the manager transaction that was generated and added to a PR.

1. Will I have any wrong, incorrect and not fully supported functionality during testing on the test/mainnet networks (UI+gnosis safe smart contracts) if I do not wait for that PR and make this deployment by myself?
2. Can this cause any delays or speeds the process up if I propose my transaction in PR directly to https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory
3. Does the manager anything else except creating this transaction, so I could be sure that everything goes well.
4. For how long it could take to wait for the response from managers for issues that were created here? https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory/issues

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. The only difference between contracts deployed through Safe's singleton factory is that they'll be deployed deterministically to canonical addresses. You can configure your setup to use custom addresses.
2. You do not have access to the deployer private key. You can't propose a PR
3. The question is unclear
4. There's no defined timeline internally because this shouldn't be blocking since the interface and infrastructure can be configured to use custom non-canonical addresses.